# Firebase Service worker error in Messaging and Firebase Hosting

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-hosting

I want to create a mini web app to test Firebase Cloud Messaging for web apps. I would like to use Firebase Hosting to host my web app.

**ERROR:**

On my browser after allowing the notification pop up, I got this
error:

> FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default
> service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope
> ('https://XXXX.firebaseapp.com/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope')
> with script ('https://XXXX.firebaseapp.com/firebase-messaging-sw.js'):
> A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.
> (messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration).

## Heading

CODE:

```
var firebaseConfig = {

  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  databaseURL: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: ""
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.requestPermission()

  .then(function() {
    return messaging.getToken();
  }).then(function(token) {
    console.log(token)

  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  })
```

Comment: navigator.serviceWorker.register('./sw.js').then((registration) => {
    messaging.useServiceWorker(registration);
    messaging.requestPermission()
        .then(function () {
            return messaging.getToken();
        }).then(function (token) {
            console.log(token)

        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
});

Comment: add "navigator.serviceWorker.register" then working proper :p

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `firebase-messaging-sw.js` is not available in your **server** root.

Comment: firebase-messaging-sw.js it's available in root, and still not working